# StateListDrawable behaving strange

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

I have this StateListDrawable:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {
            firstColor, secondColor });
StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed },
            new ColorDrawable(onClickColor));
sld.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, gd);
```

This is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:baselineAligned="true" 
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/actionButtonBack"
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/actionButton3"
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionButton2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/actionButton2"
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionButton1" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/actionButton1"
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:padding="4dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionButton3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionButtonBack"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

And then I set the drawable like this:

```
tv.setClickable(false);
tv.setTextColor(textViewColor);
actionBack.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
action2.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
action3.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
tv.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
pb.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
```

When I click in the actionBack button, the whole layout becomes the color I have as onClickButton.

I just want it to behave as if I had pressed a regular-xml-defined button drawable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the layout_width of the 'tv' (TextView with id android:id="@+id/tvTitle") is 'wrap_content' so when a color is applied to this view it takes the whole boundary you either need to hardcode the layout_width of TextView or apply color as ShapeDrawable with hardcoded width. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: The problem with that is that it doesn't have a fixed width. It's as long as the layout requires it to be, since the progressbar and the buttons can be hidden.

Comment: I've tried what you told me to do. Right now when I click a button, the TextView bg becomes null. However when I switch screen orientation, it comes back to what it should be.

Comment: Yeah, the bounds are applied on runtime and not hardcoded. For the sake of try, just set layout_width of to some dip value and see whether it work or not. Then tell me the results or rather it is helpful if you provide screenshot.

Comment: Ok, tried it. The best part is that it behaves differently depending on API version. In gingerbread, the tv drawable gets to null when I press the button. In ICS, the drawable stays the same... even if I click on the button. I mean, there's no change on the button when it's clicked.